# How to setup the two RelativeLayout in Framelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

In the `Fragment` , when the code in `if else` function detect error , it will set the `setVisibility` of `Framelayout` to `VISIBLE` like the following pseudo code.

I want the view on the top , so I use the `framelayout`.

```
public static FrameLayout reconnect_layout;
reconnect_layout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.reconnect_layout);

if(error) {
reconnect_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else(
    //do nothing
}
```

It will show the `framelayout` when `error` is true.
But the `layout` in `framelayout` is confusing like the following picture.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1K3BXnzMP5CLWQyME5ZdEZ0T0E/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1K3BXnzMP5CbkQxRVByMzF5anc/edit?usp=sharing

When the phone is vertical , the `view` look like a little abnormal.
Only the position of last two widget(Imgbtn_reconnect and reconnect_text) are abnormal.

And the phone is horizontal , the `view` is disorder.

I want `second RelativeLayout` below `second RelativeLayout`. But it can not use `layout_below`

The code of this `xml` is like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/player_surface_frame"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/player_surface"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/reconnect_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_buttonlayout1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_buttonlayout1"
        android:background="#000000">          

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_imgbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:src="@drawable/phone"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/connect"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:src="@drawable/break1"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/break_image"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:src="@drawable/camera_break"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Reconnect_text_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/break_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/connection_break_message"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/Imgbtn_reconnect"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/reconnect" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reconnect_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Reconnect"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_buttonlayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_buttonlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#444444" >

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/imageBackground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/SettingButton"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SettingButton"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/smart_cam"
                />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/SettingButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/FileSavebutton"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/parmeter_setting" />



            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/FileSavebutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/save_in_camera" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TimeStampLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/RecordState"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />

                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/RecordTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />

        </LinearLayout> 

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_buttonlayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#454749"
         >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_buttonlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/FileButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="#454749"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/file_viewer"/>



             <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/photo_record_mode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="#454749"
                android:src="@drawable/recordmode"/>

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/recordButton"
                 android:layout_width="80dp"
                 android:layout_height="80dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:background="#454749"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:src="@drawable/record" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to modify to make the widgets in Framlayout is normal ? 
I want `second RelativeLayout` below `second RelativeLayout`. But it can not use `layout_below`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need a FrameLayout? FrameLayout does not place one view above the other on the screen, it draws  one view and then draws another view in the same coordinates. For example, it can darken an image by first drawing the original image and then drawing a semi-transparent view whose background is #80000000.

For your purpose you can use, say, a LinearLayout, and programmatically set the visibility of one view to GONE and of the other to VISIBLE.

Comment: But I have other Framelayout , so I want to use framelayout to overlay all the layout. I try to modify the framelayout to LinearLayout. It will crash due to other framelayout.

Comment: I post the all of xml file

Comment: `android:layout_below="@+id/top_buttonlayout1"` -- + is not needed, it means "create a new one"

Comment: In addition, I see the problem that you have two views whose height is defined as match_parent. I would probably try LinearLayout with layout_height="0dip" and layout_weight= _something_